# JavaScript - Property Lifetime and Constructor Method Triggering

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I really want to have Date.now() available as a property, not a function call or method.  In other words I want clock.now.go to return a unix timestamp.  I cannot get it to work.  The returned timestamp is stagnant from the original call.  Below is the code with console results shown.  Is it possible to trigger a new timestamp by calling a property, or is a function call, i.e., '()' required?

```
//Revealing Module Pattern (Public & Private) 
var clock = (function() {

    // object to expose as public via return
    var pub = {};

    //constructor function
    function Now() {
        this.getNow = function() {
            return ( Date.now() );
        };
        this.go = this.getNow();
    }

    //private
    var now = new Now();
    //public
    pub.test1 = now;
    pub.test1.go;  //clock.test1.go returns 1461888755076
    pub.test1.getNow();  //clock.test1.getNow() returns 1461888767477 (GOOD)
    pub.test2 = now.getNow();  //clock.test2 returns 1461888755076 (STALE)
    pub.test3 = now.go;  //clock.test3 returns 1461888755076 (STALE)
    //Return just the public parts
    return pub;
}());
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be presented as a property, but actually be a live function call, then you can use a [Javacript getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```
//Revealing Module Pattern (Public & Private) 
var clock = (function() {

    // object to expose as public via return
    var pub = {};

    Object.defineProperty(pub, "now", {
        get: function () { 
            return Date.now();
        }
    });
    return pub;
}());

console.log(clock.now);   // returns live time
```

---

Or, it could be condensed to this:

```
//Revealing Module Pattern (Public & Private) 
var clock = (function() {

    // object to expose as public via return
    var pub = { 
        get now() { 
            return Date.now();
        }
     };
     return pub;
}());

console.log(clock.now);   // returns live time
```

Or, even just this (without the enclosing module pattern):

```
var clock = { 
    get now() { 
        return Date.now();
    }
 };

console.log(clock.now);   // returns live time
```

Comment: Added example of a getter that returns the live time.

Comment: + for the last snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a getter like this

```js
var obj = {
           _time : "",
           get time () {
             this._time = new Date();
             return this._time;
           },
           set time(val) {
             this._time = val;
           }
};

document.write("<pre>" + obj.time + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Though in this case the result  of *get* will be that *_time* is assigned a new Date object. However, after *set* it might be anything and the next time *get* is accessed it will return a new Date, so what was the point of *set*?

Comment: Just convention :)

Comment: I guess my point (poorly expressed) is that *get* is acting like a setter.

Comment: Yes true.. it's just a function and while getting the value you can still set it beforehand. The point is, when you access the property you want to have that moment's timestamp so that's how it is. Actually better done in @jfriend00's 3rd snippet.